# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str // Trying to get value of key

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a key from a value that I am returned with, but when i use the easy approach to just get the value of a specific key I get the error: **TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str**

I also tried .get() method, but it did not work either. Could someone please point me out what I am doing wrong?

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = 'http://192.168.250.1/ajax.app?SessionId=8ef05397-ef00-451a-bc1c-c0d61
5a4811d&service=getDp&plantItemId=1413'
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> dict = response.read()
>>> dict
'{"service":"getDp","plantItemId":"1413","value":" 21.4","unit":"\xc2\xb0C"}'
>>> dict['value']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like 'dict' is a variable of type string, not a dictionary. You should parse the string into a suitable dictionary format (like JSON). Here's a code that will resolve that issue:

```
import json
json_string = response.read()
dict = json.loads(json_string)
```

Now, for `dict['value']` you will get what you need.

Comment: Worth noting that this will correctly return a unicode value for the 'unit' whereas the `literal_eval` solution will return a byte string on Python 2 or go wrong on Python 3.

Comment: May i ask why I get returned --  u' 21.3'  -- Why is that "u" there?

Answer (score 4):

`response.read()` is returning an object of type `string` and not a dictionary and you can index a string using only integer indices and hence you are getting your error.

You need to parse this string and convert it to a dictionary. To convert a string of a dictionary back to a dictionary you can do this:

```
import ast
dict = ast.literal_eval(dict)
print dict['value']
```

Tried it on my machine with Python 2.7 and it works.

Comment: If the original text was intended to be json, then probably better to use an actual json decoder.